# Upgrade installation interrupted, and system hangs on login

Tags: 12.04, unity, upgrade, 12.10

This problem started after upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10.  I just used the upgrade option from the `Update Manager`. Once, there was a connection failure. And it quit, but told me that all downloaded packages have been kept. Then a while later, after connection resumed, I started again. It all got over, and it finished upgrading, and then it said "Restarting the computer". Then it went into the Ubuntu restart/start-load screen and hung there forever.

I powered off the laptop, and restarted the laptop. Then after the start screen, the login screen loaded, which was sort of in a stretched 800x600 res. I log in, and I don't see anything at all except the wallpaper. No other component of the interface has loaded.

Need a fix or a safe way out. I don't even mind rolling back to `12.04` with just all my files intact.

Comment: Some possible options: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076

Answer (score 2):

Well, I just removed `fglrx` and then everything works fine now. (Almost fine)

My DELL Inspiron has severe heating problems with Ubuntu, which works quiet on Windows7. The fan makes a lot of noise, and the laptop heats up like mad. This happened with 11.04 too, and until I installed fglrx drivers for my ATI card, I had the issue. And even with fglrx, it was just a little better. Never normal.

But now I'm forced to continue without fglrx, because of the problem! And the heating problem is crazy again!! Too bad, Ubuntu 12.10, Y U NO SUPPORT FGLRX?